# Is there any way to render or download pdf in android using inappbrowser

Tags: android, pdf, ionic-native, inappbrowser

I am using @ionic-native/in-app-browser and trying to load pdf link which is within in app browser instance.
Blank screen displays when pdf url is clicked.
I tried all the event listeners but nothing worked.
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Note: As per my analysis, Android does not support this through in-app-browser.